# Receiving a URL fragment server side in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to .NET and this in my first question, so I apologize if my approach is incorrect.

I'm following the Meta documentation to implement [Instagram business login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/business-login-for-instagram) and get a user access token, in my ASP.NET MVC app (I'm using the .NET framework 4.8 runtime).

The problem is that after a user completes the Business Login for Instagram flow, he will be redirected to the URL assigned to the redirect_uri and the necessary tokens will be appended in a URL fragment (#).

And the redirect_uri points to an ASP.NET MVC controller server-side, which means the tokens in the URL fragment will be disregarded at the browser level and cannot be accessed at the server.

Is there any solution around this? Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC to add client-side JS to intercept the request and change the URL fragment into query parameters, then send the request to the controller?

This is the redirected uri format after user completes login flow:

```
{redirect-url}?
  #access_token={access-token}
  &data_access_expiration_time={data-access-expiration-time}
  &expires_in={expires-in}
  &long_lived_token={long-lived-token}
```

All is in the Meta Instagram documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to extract the fragment on the front end?. And then redirect to the same URL with the tokens as query parameters  Add the script logic in the asp.net view.

```
<script>
  var fragment = window.location.hash.substring(1);

  var access_token = fragment.split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
  var data_access_expiration_time = fragment.split('&')[1].split('=')[1];

  // Redirect to URL with queryparams 
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + 
    "?access_token=" + access_token + 
    "&data_access_expiration_time=" + data_access_expiration_time;
</script>
```

Ideally though the entire authentication flow should be on the server side.